# open a form to find specific record in VBA access

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'am using Ms access , I make a button that open a form and find a specific data

```
Private Sub Command134_Click()

Docmd.OpenForm "facture_vente_new_ operations", acNormal, "", "[Id_facture]=" [&Id_facture], , acNormal
```

when [Id_facture] is not empty it works find but when it's empty it gives an error

Comment: Why is `&` character within fieldname brackets? Did you mistype this code instead of copy/paste?

Answer (score 0):

What do you want the form to show, if `[Id_facture]` is empty?
All records? No record at all?

Use this criteria, to show all records if `[Id_facture]` is empty:

```vb
IIf(Len(vbNullString & [Id_facture]) = 0, "", "[Id_facture]=" & [Id_facture])
```

Or use this criteria, to show no record at all if `[Id_facture]` is empty:

```vb
IIf(Len(vbNullString & [Id_facture]) = 0, False, "[Id_facture]=" & [Id_facture])
```

For the user to get an info instead opening the form use this:

```vb
If Len(vbNullString & [Id_facture]) = 0 Then
    MsgBox "'Id_facture' is empty. Please provide a value.", vbInformation, "Attention"
Else
    Docmd.OpenForm "facture_vente_new_ operations", acNormal, "", "[Id_facture]=" & [Id_facture], , acNormal
End If
```

Comment: Thank you bro for responding me . I like when I click on button , if filed [Id_facture] is empty show msgbox "[Id_facture] is empty" else open a form and find a specific data where [Id_facture] is match ...... and where can I add this criteria in my code ???

Comment: Ok, I editited my answer. Have fun with it.